# Pandas: Not able to set a cell value based on a condition on other column

Tags: python

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID   Score   Bid_Doc_ID
1      67       3
2      -1       2
3      -1       7
```

I want to set `Bid_Doc_ID` field to -1 where `Score` == -1

For this, I a using the following code:

```
df = df.loc[df['Score']==-1,'Bid_Doc_ID']=-1
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Even I tried :

```
df = df.loc[df['Score'].astype(str)==-1,'Bid_Doc_ID']=-1
```

Still getting the same error.

My Expected result:

```
ID   Score   Bid_Doc_ID
1      67        3
2      -1       -1
3      -1       -1
```

The issue seems to be quite trivial, but somewhat I am missing out things!

Comment: try removing the first  `df =` . Simply `df.loc[df['Score']==-1,'Bid_Doc_ID']=-1`

Comment: This update is done in place, you don't need to assign it back to the df.  Remove the df= part

Comment: Is anybody else confused by the error message? I tried `x = [1,2];x = x[0] = [2,3];print(x)` and didn't expect the output `[[...], 3]` without an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the part of your code that assigns a new `df` :

```
df = df.loc[df['Score']==-1,'Bid_Doc_ID']=-1 # change
df.loc[df['Score']==-1,'Bid_Doc_ID']=-1 # to be this
```

Or, an alternative, you can get what you need using `np.where`?

```
import numpy as np
df['Bid_Doc_ID'] = np.where(df['Score'] == -1, -1, df['Bid_Doc_ID'])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you ran `df = df.loc[df['Score'].astype(str)==-1,'Bid_Doc_ID']=-1`, it looks like you overwrote your df with an integer or a boolean (which is why the `'int' object has no attribute 'loc'` error). Try inspecting the value of df to verify that.

It will happen a lot if you modify a DF in place, which is never a good idea, it's always best to assign the modified dataframe to a new variable e.g. `df_fixed`, it will save you a lot of time debugging stuff, or even worse, releasing bugs in production.

Try the following, it's not too concise, but it uses pure pandas methods and methods chaining, which is the recommended way these days.

```py
bid_doc_id_fixed = df.apply(lambda x: -1 if x['Score'] == -1 else x['Bid_Doc_ID'], axis=1)

df_fixed = df.assign(Bid_Doc_ID=bid_doc_id_fixed)
```